# turtlebot_gazebo world not loading models

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm with Ubuntu 13.04 x64 and I have installed:

```
Package: gazebo
Version: 1.9.1-2~raring
Package: ros-hydro-turtlebot-gazebo
Version: 2.1.0-1raring-20130910-0236-+0000
```

When I run:

```
$ gazebo /usr/share/gazebo-1.9/worlds/willowgarage.world
```

It all works fine, the world is loaded and the models are cached at ~/.gazebo/models/

On the other hand if I run:

```
$ gazebo /opt/ros/hydro/share/turtlebot_gazebo/worlds/playground.world
```

It DOES NOT load any models:

```
Error [ModelDatabase.cc:408] Unable to download model[model://dumpster/meshes/dumpster.dae]
Error [SystemPaths.cc:371] File or path does not exist[""]
Error [MeshShape.cc:64] No mesh specified
Error [ModelDatabase.cc:408] Unable to download model[model://cube_20k/meshes/cube_20k.stl]
Error [SystemPaths.cc:371] File or path does not exist[""]
Error [MeshShape.cc:64] No mesh specified
Msg Waiting for model database update to complete...
Error [ModelDatabase.cc:408] Unable to download model[model://dumpster/meshes/dumpster.dae]
```

Gazebo GUI opens, and if I insert the models manually using the GUI library (Dumpster, Cube 20k, etc), they do get cached and next time I run it they load fine.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4399/turtlebot_gazebo-world-not-loading-models/) by [nunojpg](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/493/nunojpg/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 33 on 2013-09-19

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/143/bit-pirate/) on 2013-09-25**:
We had the same issue here in our lab. It can be solved by manually adding those missing models from the online database to the world. The next time Gazebo is started the models are loaded correctly. However, this can't be the right way to do it. We have ticketed that problem here: https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_simulator/issues/17

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/143/bit-pirate/) on 2013-09-25**:
Following up here: https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/806/gzclient-does-not-download-missing-models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You should see this message on the command line:

```
Warning [ModelDatabase.cc:356] Getting models from[http://gazebosim.org/models/]. This may take a few seconds.
```

It may take a minute or so to download the models.

If that doesn't work then you may need Gazebo 2.0. Since you are using ROS hydro, which relies on Gazebo 1.9.2, I would recommend against installing Gazebo 2.0. Instead, you can grab the models manually.

```
wget http://gazebosim.org/models/dumpster/model.tar.gz .
tar xvf model.tar.gz -C ~/.gazebo/models
```

Repeat that for `cube_20k`.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-10-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3